# L2TP pre-shared key

Tags: android, vpn

We're writing a VPN client for Android and need to support L2TP.  We're having issues with specifying the L2TP pre-shared key (PSK).  Is there a way that this can be specified from a user application, and if so, what is it?

Comment: Hi, @jas I need to implement L2TP VPN for android too, I hope u found the solution if yes please share it, since it is urgent for me.